# Android: Разница между scrollview и recyclerview

Tags: android

Проходил собеседование и озадачил там один вопрос: какая разница между scrollview и  recyclerview? Когда и какой лучше использовать? Какие проблемы могут возникнуть?

Как я понимаю разница между ними в том, что scrollview не имеет имплантации в java коде, просто упрощённый recyclerview. И для простой прокрутки достаточно scrollview, ео если хотим сделать взаимодействия с элементами внутри прокрутки, то лучше использовать recyclerview.

Это так вообще? Когда и какой лучше использовать? Какая вообще между ними разница?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> какая разница между scrollview и recyclerview?

Самое главное (имхо):

- `recyclerview` используется для списков, он переиспользует представление и позволяет выводить неограниченное кол-во элементов.
- `scrollview` - по сути это просто скролл для «фиксированного» контента.

> scrollview не имеет имплантации в java коде, просто **упрощённый** recyclerview

Скорее наоборот, `scrollview` - это упрощённый `recyclerview` (хотя это разные элементы и подобное сравнение неуместно).

> И для простой прокрутки достаточно scrollview, ео если хотим сделать взаимодействия с элементами внутри прокрутки, то лучше использовать recyclerview.

Почти...

> Когда и какой лучше использовать?

`scrollview` лучше использовать для вывода контента, который прописан в xml разметке (фиксированный контент, особо не меняющийся в процессе использования).

`recyclerview` нужно использовать для вывода любых списков, но с одинаковой структурой. Т.е. каждый элемент будет выглядеть одинаково (в большинстве случаев). Такой список может содержать не ограниченное кол-во элементов и меняться динамически в любой момент времени.

Comment: Спасибо за хороший ответ!